# problema con select option

Tags: laravel, select, options

tengo un problema con un select, lo que sucede es que estoy editando un registro, el cual tiene un select option y el cual esta relacionado a una tabla, mi problema es que al momento de que capture el valor del option me muestra el principal, y no el que estaba seleccionado, les muestro el codigo y el problema:

HTML

```html
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('sucursales.update',$sucursalfind->id ) }}"  role="form">
{{ csrf_field() }}
  <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
     <label>Region</label>
     <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" id="listadoRegiones" name="id_region" value="{{ $sucursalfind->id_region }}">
     @foreach ($listRegiones as $listadoR)
     <option value="{{ $listadoR['id_region'] }}">{{$listadoR['nombre'] }} 
        </option>
     @endforeach
   </select>
</form>
```

```
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

SE SUPONE QUE DEBIO APARECER ESTA, YA QUE ES LA NUMERO 11

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> PARA RESUMIR!

Se supone que esta seleccionada la opción numero 11 (Primera Imagen), pero al abrir el modal, muestra la opción numero 1 (tarapaca, Segunda Imagen), pero deberia mostrar la 11 (Aysen, Tercera Imagen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No te selecciona por defecto la región ya que el value esta dentro del selector, en este caso deberás compararlo dentro del `foreach` cuando recorras las regiones.

```
<select class="form-control" id="listadoRegiones" name="id_region">
    @foreach ($listRegiones as $listadoR)
    <option value="{{ $listadoR['id_region'] }}"
    @if ($listadoR['id_region'] == $sucursalfind->id_region)
      selected="selected"
    @endif
    >{{$listadoR['nombre'] }} 
    </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Espero te sirva!

Comment: tengo una duda, te faltaron cerrar algunas cosas?, que un ejemplo el selected="selected" no tienen etiqueta y el option le fatla ">", por otro lado, talvez dices que todo eso es una linea??

Comment: por que no me funciona

Comment: No, no falto cerrar, lo hcie de esa forma basicamente para que se pudiera enteder, aun asi no deberia darte error.

Comment: no me da error, pero tampoco me lo selecciona jaja

Comment: me equivoque, copie mal el codigo! funciona sin problemas! gracias por tu tiempo amigo!

Comment: genial! saludos!